# Is indefinite exponential economic growth possible?

Tags: economic-growth

Economic growth is frequently expressed as a % of GDP.  Proponents of a [steady-state economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_state_economy) postulate that perpetual exponential economic growth is impossible and that any system relying on it is inherently unstable. Is this true?

Is indefinite exponential economic growth possible?

(See also: *[Are there fundamental reasons why (exponential) economic growth is highly desirable?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/455/332)*)

Comment: The answer, of course, is yes in some models and no in others.  If you're asking for a survey of the growth literature, this question is too broad.  Otherwise, it should be about a specific model or class of models.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg - what about real life, instead of models which can be constructed either way?

Comment: @DeerHunter:  In real life, the Universe will pretty much die out in another $10^{15}$ years or so, so the answer is no, you can't have exponential growth "forever".  If you want to ask a sensible question about this, it needs to be in the context of a model.

Comment: [Kenneth Boulding](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Exponential_growth#Quotes): "Anyone who believes exponential growth can go on forever in a finite world is either a madman or an economist."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Steven Landsburg pointed out, indefinite anything isn't possible given the eventual heat death of the universe.

[Von Neumann posited machines capable of indefinite growth in population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_spacecraft#Von_Neumann_probes) (and theoretically production and consumption), so in theory, it would be possible for a time.

[Sagan's Response](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1983QJRAS..24..113S) however argued if such things existed that we would have already observed them, and that they would destroy whole galaxies *en masse*.

That's probably the closest answer you can get to a question like this.

Comment: but what if economic growth is in intangibles? If the future growth of the world is all in videogames and philosophy, would it still destroy whole galaxies en masse?

Comment: Probably. Generation of intangibles still consumes energy, requiring fuel. Not to mention people do the thinking and appreciating.